# what would you call someone if

Tags: meaning-in-context

What would you call someone that has died but got given a second chance? They are now alive. What would you call that person?

Comment: Lucky, probably. Or a zombie, depending on whether the context is a horror movie or not.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Are you talking about fiction or real life? (In real life, they were arguably never really dead, just *near dead*.) What do you mean by *second chance*?

Answer (score 2):

**resurrectee**

The person has been **resurrected**

> *resurrect*
>
> Restore (a dead person) to life.
>
> ‘he queried whether Jesus was indeed resurrected’
>
> https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resurrect

As such, I would say that that person is a ***resurrectee***

Answer (score 1):

[Revenant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revenant) : one that returns after death or a long absence

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far talk of second chances within the same life, but the adjective *[reincarnate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reincarnate)* can be used to describe someone who has died and been given a second chance through another life.